Cypher query optimization
Can the cypher query
MATCH p=(n: customer) - [r*1. {max_hops}] -> (m: customer) In › return nodes (p) as nodes, relationships(p) as relationships, length(p) as hops

be memory optimized but yielding the same result?
I am trying to find 3 hops relationships in a neo4j graph using this query , it’s working for small graph but for bigger graphs it’s giving memory error

Your Cypher query seems to have typos. Please fix your question.

I think there are multiple aspects to your question.

Do you have more than 1 path between two customers? Probably. And if that is the case, do you want all paths, the shortest or ...? So, this part is about making sure the query is "correct" and you have different options to express the path pattern (check shortest and path patterns in the cypher manual). If you want exactly 3 hops and in one direction, use -[*3..3]->

Make the query run at scale. To me, it looks like a reporting query, so it may return large results/run for a bit of time. So much time so it probably does not matter if the data changes as the query runs. So chunk it up to run in many transactions like this:


:auto 
match (n:customer)
call (n) {
    match p=(n)-[*3..3]->(m:customer)
    return nodes (p) as nodes, relationships(p) as relationships, length(p) as hops
} in transactions of 10_000 rows
return nodes, relationships, hops

Adjust the in transactions of 10_000 rows part to what the database instance can handle.

Getting the results back (assuming it is million of paths), did we get wiser? What question did we answer? I can only read between the lines and guess. But likely you are after communities in your customer graph. So you could for instance project customer nodes and some relationship types and run the graph data science algorithm wcc.

